# Win32 program compiles but no window appears

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

i am compiling a simple Win32 api program but the problem is that it compiles fine but no window appears. I checked the process in taskmanager and the program is there but doesn't show up a window. I am using CodeBlocks IDE 10.05 with GNU GCC compiler under windows 7 32-bit.
I know there is a similar question here on stackoverflow but the solution given there was a'==' instead of '='.  here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

/* Global Vars */
HINSTANCE hInst;
HWND wndHandle;
int winWidth = 640;
int winHeight = 480;

//func prototypes
bool InitWindow(HINSTANCE hInst, int width, int height);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
/********************************************************
* WINMAIN FUNCTION
*********************************************************/
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
hInst = hInstance;

//app window

if (!InitWindow(hInst, winWidth, winHeight))
{
    return false;
}

// MESSAGE LOOP
MSG msg = {0};
while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
{
    //window messages
    while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL,0,0, PM_REMOVE) == TRUE)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    //additional logic
}
return (int)msg.wParam;
 }

/*******************************************************************
* InitWindow
* Inits and creates and main app window
* Inputs - application instance - HINSTANCE
           Window width - int
           Window height - int
* Outputs - true if successful, false if failed - bool
*******************************************************************/
bool InitWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance, int width, int height)
{
// Register class
WNDCLASSEX wcex;
wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon          = 0;
wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH) + (COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
wcex.lpszClassName  = TEXT("DirectX 10 Example");
wcex.hIconSm        = 0;

if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
{
  return false;
}

// resize window
RECT rect = { 0, 0, width, height };
AdjustWindowRect(&rect, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, false);

// create the window from the class above
wndHandle = CreateWindow(   TEXT("DX 10 Example"),
                            TEXT("DX10 WINDOW"),
                            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                            CW_USEDEFAULT,
                            CW_USEDEFAULT,
                            rect.right - rect.left,
                            rect.bottom - rect.top,
                            0,
                            0,
                            hInstance,
                            0);
if(wndHandle == 0)
{
    return false;
}
ShowWindow(wndHandle, SW_SHOW);
UpdateWindow(wndHandle);
return true;
}
/*******************************************************************
* WndProc
* The main window procedure for the application
* Inputs - application window handle - HWND
           message sent to the window - UINT
           wParam of the message being sent - WPARAM
           lParam of the message being sent - LPARAM
* Outputs - LRESULT
*******************************************************************/
 LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
 {
   switch (message)
{
    // Allow the user to press the escape key to end the application
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch(wParam)
        {
            // Check if the user hit the escape key
            case VK_ESCAPE:
              PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
    break;

        // The user hit the close button, close the application
    case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Use assert() to catch mistakes.

Comment: I recommend using msvc for windows development - it is arguably the best windows compiler (and express edition is free but also very good)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have 
wcex.lpszClassName  = TEXT("DirectX 10 Example");

and

wndHandle = CreateWindow(   TEXT("DX 10 Example"),
                            TEXT("DX10 WINDOW"),

Comment: many thanks, problem solved, an awful mistake :(, but why the compiler wasn't complaining about this? shouldn't it be?

Comment: @Polizel: The compiler cannot guess that you made a typo. That's why you should *always* use constants (not literals) for values that need to be repeated.

Answer (score 3):

Your have to use the same class name for "CreateWindow" as you used for "RegisterClass".

In your source code those two differ:

```
wcex.lpszClassName  = TEXT("DirectX 10 Example");
...
wndHandle = CreateWindow(TEXT("DX 10 Example"), ...
```